# How to format array to xml?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, string

I need to format an xml response to 
1asdasd
but so far i am only getting this. 
1asdasd
sorry in advance for poor explanation

SimpleXML

```
$arr =array('extra name="remote"'=>'1asdasd');

<extra name="remote">1asdasd</extra>
```

Comment: <extra name="remote">1asdasd</extra>   //need it in the following format

Comment: have tried this but did not work   $data = array(
                'title' => ' Users Information',
                'users' => array(
                    array('name="overdarat"'=>'extra','data'=>'0','attr name="remote"'=>'1asdasd'),
                    array('name' => 'Merry Moe', 'email' => 'merry@moe.com'),
                    array('name' => 'Hellary Riss', 'email' => 'hellary@riss.com')
                )
            );

Comment: 1) Don't post code in the comment section, it's hard to read, you can edit your question and add your code. 2)The snippet you show is just an array, it doesn't show your attempt to solve the problem, please also add your work so we can see what is the problem with it and we can start from there.